# exceptions and monad transformers

Tags: haskell, monad-transformers

I'm using the EitherT monad transformer. Combining it with the IO monad, I'm afraid I would get an exception and it would not be caught.

Indeed the exception just passes through:

```
import Control.Monad.Trans
import Control.Error
import System.Directory

main = runEitherT testEx >>= print

testEx :: EitherT String IO ()
testEx = lift $ removeFile "non existing filename"
```

But the `EitherT` otherwise fits the bill perfectly to convey to callers the error. So I want to use that, not throw exceptions...

I looked at `try` from Control.Exception:

```
try :: Exception e => IO a -> IO (Either e a)
```

It looks to be exactly what I want, it would fit in my EitherT IO stack... (probably with an added `hoistEither` and maybe `fmapL` and it starts looking verbose though) But a naive `lift $ try` doesn't typecheck.

I'm sure this problem has been solved thousands of times, but I can't find any good link describing this exact issue. How is this supposed to be solved?

**EDIT** By "how is this supposed to be solved", I was interested in the idiomatic solution, what would be the standard way to handle that in haskell. From the answers so far, it seems the idiomatic way is to let the exceptions be thown and handle them higher-up. Seems like a bit counter-intuitive to have two flows of control and return paths, but it is apparently the way it's meant to be done.

Comment: The [`lifted-base`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lifted-base-0.2.3.0) seems to be what you're looking for, which I found thanks to [this post](http://chromaticleaves.com/posts/guard-io-with-errort.html).

Comment: Thank you, that's very interesting. Too bad he doesn't give the link to the discussion he triggered on haskell-cafe. I hope there's more that that, though, a "better" solution, otherwise it seems it would be idiomatic to ignore the problem, if the answer is not immediate and used by almost everybody...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't want to `lift` `try`ing the computation, then you'd get an `Exception e => EitherT a IO (Either e ())`.

```
testEx :: (Exception e, MonadTrans m) => m IO (Either e ())
testEx = lift . try $ fails
```

You don't want the error in the result, you want to integrate the error into the `EitherT`. You want to integrate `try`ing somethign with your `EitherT`

```
testEx :: (Exception e) => EitherT e IO ()
testEx = EitherT . try $ fails
```

We'll do this in general, then get just the message you want.

#### Integrate try with EitherT

You can extract the idea of integrating `try` with `EitherT`

```
tryIO :: (Exception e) => IO a -> EitherT e IO a
tryIO = EitherT . try
```

Or, for any underlying `MonadIO` as

```
tryIO :: (Exception e, MonadIO m) => IO a -> EitherT e m a
tryIO = EitherT . liftIO . try
```

(`tryIO` conflicts with a name from `Control.Error`. I couldn't come up with another name for this.)

You can then say you are willing to catch any exception. `SomeException` will catch all exceptions. If you are only interested in specific exceptions, use a different type. See [Control.Exception](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Control-Exception.html) for the details. If you aren't sure what you want to catch, you probably only want to catch `IOException`s; this is what `tryIO` from `Control.Error` does; see the last section.

```
anyException :: EitherT SomeException m a -> EitherT SomeException m a
anyException = id
```

You only want to keep the error message from the exception

```
message :: (Show e, Functor m) => EitherT e m a -> EitherT String m a
message = bimapEitherT show id
```

Then you can write

```
testEx :: EitherT String IO ()
testEx = message . anyException . tryIO $ fails
```

#### Integrate try with MonadError

You can instead integrate `try`ing something with any `MonadError`, using `MonadError` and `MonadIO` to penetrate the transformer stack.

```
import Control.Monad.Except

tryIO :: (MonadError e m, MonadIO m, Exception e) => IO a -> m a
tryIO = (>>= either throwError return) . liftIO . try
```

You can write `testEx` in terms of this `tryIO` and `anyException` and `message` from the previous section

```
testEx :: EitherT String IO ()
testEx = message . anyException . tryIO $ fails
```

#### tryIO from Control.Error

The `tryIO` from Control.Error is essentially our first `tryIO`, except it only catches `IOException`s instead of any exception. It's actually defined as

```
tryIO :: (MonadIO m) => IO a -> EitherT IOException m a
tryIO = EitherT . liftIO . try
```

We can use it with `message` to write `testEx` as

```
testEx :: EitherT String IO ()
testEx = message . tryIO $ fails
```

Comment: thank you. i'll review the explanations in details ASAP. i think i did badly formulate my question in a way. I assumed that doing that is something I should do, which is good and idiomatic. At this point I start to think that the idiomatic way is to handle these exceptions higher-up. But your answer is interesting nonetheless, thank you!

Comment: You might be interested in reading Gabriel Gonzalez's post when he announced `errors`, the package where the `Control.Error` you are using came from. http://www.haskellforall.com/2012/07/errors-10-simplified-error-handling.html The comments discuss a lot about which exceptions it's ok to catch, which influenced the definition of `tryIO` in `Control.Error`. It's amusing that we reached almost identical definitions with exactly the same name.

Comment: Using typeclasses to deal with transformer stacks is idiomatic but unnecessary. The `transformers` package deliberately omits typeclasses because there are multiple different ways to deal with them: `mtl`, `monads-tf`, `monads-fd`, etc., though we seem to be standardizing on `mtl`. There are multiple type classes for something like `EitherT`. `mtl` has two: there's the `MonadError` in `Control.Monad.Except` and another `MonadError` in `Control.Monad.Error.Class`. I'd use the one from `Control.Monad.Except`. I don't know where the `MonadThrow` typeclass Michael suggests comes from.

Comment: As my comment mentions, `MonadThrow` comes from the `exceptions` package.

Answer (score 18):

I actually think `EitherT` is *not* the right thing to do here. What you're trying to say is "`IO` is for side-effects, and `EitherT` is for exceptions." But that's not true: `IO` *always* has the potential to result in an exception, so all you're doing is adding a false sense of security to your API, and introducing two ways that exceptions can be thrown instead of one. In addition, instead of using the well structured `SomeException` favored by `IO`, you're reducing down to `String`, which throws away information.

Anyway, if you're convinced that this is what you want to do, it's not too difficult. It looks something like:

```
eres <- liftIO $ try x
case eres of
    Left e -> throwError $ show (e :: SomeException)
    Right x -> return x
```

Note, however, that this will also swallow up async exceptions, which is usually *not* what you want to do. I think a better approach for that is [enclosed-exceptions](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/enclosed-exceptions).

Comment: well I need the Either for some other aspects of the function anyway. If I didn't need IO code, that would be a Either function. I started with a pure Either function let's say, added the IO part, now I have a EitherT IO and thinking, it's a shame to have the exceptions while I can take advantage of the EitherT. On the other hand, it's true that if I start wrapping all my IO functions with a `try`, I'm not using the language as it was intended. So it seems the answer is, the idiomatic way is to let it go and have a `try` higher-up. I didn't read your links yet though, will do ASAP.

Comment: so in the end, I guess I'm a bit confused by the double message exceptions vs sum types in haskell. when which one, and why.

Comment: I'd also recommend having a look at the `exceptions` package. Instead of having your pure code live directly in `Either`, have it live in any instance of `MonadThrow`.

Comment: Looks like I have lots of researching to do. What is wrong with pure code living in `Either`? But I guess I can answer myself by googling and reading...

Comment: The only problem is that it won't unify with code in IO. By programming against a typeclass, your code will automatically work for both Either and IO without any conversion.

Answer (score 1):

This is another simple approach: Let's define a custom monad transformer just like `EitherT` is defined:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances, FunctionalDependencies #-}
import Control.Arrow (left)
import Control.Exception
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.Trans
import Control.Monad.Error
import Control.Monad.IO.Class

newtype ErrT a m b = ErrT { runErrT :: m (Either a b) }

instance (Monad m) => Monad (ErrT a m) where
    -- ...

instance (Monad m) => MonadError a (ErrT a m) where
    -- ...

instance MonadTrans (ErrT a) where
    lift = ErrT . liftM Right
```

together with the appropriate `Applicative`, `Monad` and `MonadError` instances.

Now let's add a means for an `IOError` to be converted to our error type. We can have a type class for this so that we're free in how we use the transformer.

```
class FromIOError e where
    fromIOException :: IOError -> e
```

Finally, we'll implement `MonadIO` in such a way that `liftIO` always catches `IOError`s and converts them to the pure data type in the left part:

```
instance (MonadIO m, FromIOError a) => MonadIO (ErrT a m) where
    liftIO = ErrT . liftIO . liftM (left fromIOException)
                  . (try :: IO a -> IO (Either IOError a))
```

Now if we put all this in a module and export just the data type, `runErrT`, but not the constructor `ErrT`, everything that does IO within `ErrT` will have the exceptions properly handled, because `IO` actions can be introduced only through `liftIO`.

It'd be also possible to replace `IOError` with `SomeException` and handle all exceptions, if desired.