# handling exceptions with EitherT

Tags: haskell, monad-transformers

I already asked a similar question there: [exceptions and monad transformers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25752900/exceptions-and-monad-transformers) but somehow didn't express myself correctly and got answers to another question than the one I meant to ask (at least that's how I interpret it).

I hit again this problem now, let me try again to formulate my problem...

I have to write a function taking a server which may hold an authentication key, and a target file where to save the authentication key contents.

```
saveAuthKey :: Text -> Server -> IO (Either Text Text)
```

The function may return `Left` in three cases:

1. The target path is badly formatted: doesn't start with "file://"
2. the Server does not hold an authentication key
3. there was an IO error saving the key to the file

That's a prime candidate for an `EitherT`, it seems to me.

So I start with:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Control.Error
import Control.Monad.Trans
import Data.Text (Text)
import qualified Data.Text as T
import Data.ByteString (ByteString)
import qualified Data.ByteString as BS
import Control.Exception

data Server = Server { authKey :: Maybe ByteString }

main = putStrLn "OK"

saveAuthKey :: Text -> Server -> IO (Either Text Text)
saveAuthKey path server = do
    result <- try $ runEitherT $ do
        targetFile <- hoistEither $ note "Invalid target file name"
            $ T.stripPrefix "file://" path
        key <- hoistEither $ note "No authentication key for that server!"
            $ authKey server
        lift $ BS.writeFile (T.unpack targetFile) key
```

I applied `try` on top of the `runEitherT`, so `try` wraps the result in yet another `Either`. Not quite elegant. But if I don't put the try directly there, the exception won't be caught. In my previous question I tried to put the `try` next to the `lift` inside the `runEitherT`, which also doesn't work well.

So, if you had to write such a function, with that signature, how would you handle it? I also understand the part that I should let *some* exceptions through and not catch systematically `SomeException`, I don't think it relates directly to my question. Let's say with the `try` I'll catch relevant errors (disk full, no write permission and so on).

I could not do a `try` at all, and let the caller handle it (after all this function is in the `IO` monad and therefore there is a risk), but at some point someone will have to use `try`. Also in my case I'm using the `hsqml` library and this is a call from Javascript handled in haskell and if I let exceptions through the application will crash.

**EDIT**: I commited my current solution to this problem [in this commit](https://github.com/emmanueltouzery/projectpad/commit/0e8a45591c907907ef193d3a3e34dedf961fe054#diff-3db8032838e5bd11ca929cfab1a054e4R147). However I feel something better can be achieved in this function specifically, without having to change the design of the rest of the application. Note that I catch all exceptions, which I know is not advised, but it'll do for now. Can nothing nicer really be achieved? Or am I taking the problem completely the wrong way around?

Comment: I don't understand why you want to use a monad transformer if you are going to immediately run the transformer. Perhaps you want `saveAuthKey :: Text -> Server -> EitherT YourExceptionType IO Text`? Then when you "run" `saveAuthKey` as a `IO (Either YourExceptionType Text)`, it will capture exceptions of type `YourExceptionType` and propagate everything else. However, `Text` is certainly not a good exception type...

Comment: this goes straight to javascript and I return strings to JS. I can't return/throw real exceptions. But let's ignore that. My problem is catching certain exception types the `IO` call might throw and making that fit with the `EitherT`. You ask why use a transformer to run it immediately. I want the `Either` monad effect... I can't use `Either` because there's IO involved, so I move to `EitherT`, then execute it. Seems logical to me, but maybe (likely) I'm doing it wrong.

Comment: Also if that function would trigger a FileExists exception for instance, I would think it should wrap that in the `Either` it returns, not let it throw an exception. The caller can recover from that with its `Left` case. If another unexpected exception (like OutOfMemory for instance) occurs then yet then it should let it propagate. Right?

Comment: I'm not sure what javascript has to do with it. If your IO action throws an exception, you can catch it, whether you are in `EitherT e IO a` or just `IO a`. Also, I don't know what difference it makes which particular exceptions you will be catching - you can always catch some particular ones and propagate all others. It would help if you clarified with an example what behavior of your current function is incorrect.

Comment: so I want to catch some exceptions. That is really all I want in the end. This current function as written in the question does not compile. with `try $ runEitherT` I get an `Either` within an `Either` but I want a single `Either`. It's easy to "flatten" but feels ugly. If I catch the exception within the `EitherT`, well I don't know how to do that in a satisfying way either (that was my other question). If you could complete two implementations of this function, that catch some IO exceptions, let others through, in an idiomatic way, one catch in the IO, one in the EitherT that is all I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you meant to do?  I pushed the `try` into the specific call that could throw, and made use of `bimapEitherT` to convert the exception into `Text`.

```
saveAuthKey :: ObjRef ProjectViewState -> Text -> ObjRef (Entity Server) -> IO (Either Text Text)
saveAuthKey _ path (entityVal . fromObjRef -> server) = runEitherT $ do
  (targetFile, key) <- hoistEither $
     (,) <$> note "Invalid target file name"
             (T.stripPrefix "file://" path)
         <*> note "No authentication key for that server!"
             (serverAuthKey server)
  bimapEitherT textEx (const mempty) . EitherT . try $
    BS.writeFile (T.unpack targetFile) key
```

However, I feel this is a bit overkill because the part that can throw exceptions is localized to one call (`BS.writeFile`) while the parts that can return `Left` are all pure computations that occur beforehand.  `EitherT` is nice when you have code that intertwines the `Either` and `IO` logic heavily, but here the separation is very clear.  Here's how I would write it without `EitherT`:

```
saveAuthKey :: ObjRef ProjectViewState -> Text -> ObjRef (Entity Server) -> IO (Either Text Text)
saveAuthKey _ path (entityVal . fromObjRef -> server) =
  either (return . Left) save authKey
  where authKey = (,) <$> note "Invalid target file name"
                          (T.stripPrefix "file://" path)
                      <*> note "No authentication key for that server!"
                          (serverAuthKey server)
        save (targetFile, key) = either (Left . textEx) (const (Right ""))
                             <$> try (BS.writeFile (T.unpack targetFile) key)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! For both code samples. I had in mind too to split the non-IO actions and use a tuple. And I missed `bimapEitherT` too. But the answer I was looking for was `EitherT . try` more or less. I kept trying to put a `lift` there, that was not needed obviously (need to spend some time looking at how monad transformers work in details). A bit disappointed by the boilerplate/plumbing needed with transformers but thankfully you don't need all *that* often.