# Dealing with IO exceptions inside the MonadError

Tags: haskell, exception, monad-transformers

I'm writing a function that queries a REST end-point to fetch some data, say `queryServer`:

```
queryServer :: (MonadIO m, MonadError Message m) => URL -> m String
```

The reason why I want to use the `MonadError` from `Control.Monad.Except` is that I want to have the short-circuiting behavior of this monad. So for instance it can be used as follows:

```
queryServers :: (MonadIO m, MonadError Message m) => m (String, String)
queryServers = do
  res0 <- queryServer "server0" 
  res1 <- queryServer "server1"
  return (res0, res1)
```

In this way, I do not have to worry about catching exceptions originated at `queryServer` and the function fails as soon as an error is encountered.

The problem I have with this approach (and there might be others I'm unaware of) is that I have to use some boilerplate to catch the IO exceptions and re-throw them with `throwError`:

```
queryServer url = do
  result <- liftIO $ try (fetchSomething url)
  case result of
    Left (e :: IOException) -> throwError "error when fetching"
    Right sth -> return sth

fetchSomething :: URL -> IO String
fetchSomething = undefined
```

I've seen several questions regarding the proper use of exceptions in Haskell, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25752900/exceptions-and-monad-transformers), however none of them deals with the `MonadError`.

What is the right way to dealing with IO exceptions within the `MonadError?

Comment: [tryIO](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/errors-2.1.2/docs/Control-Error-Util.html#v:tryIO)?

Comment: How would you use it in this example?

Comment: `queryServer = tryIO . fetchSomething`

Comment: But this would require that I change `Message` to `IOException` in the constraints above. I don't know if you're implying that I should do this anyway.

Comment: And the other problem with using `tryIO` is that I cannot longer leave `m` abstract, but I have to use `ExceptT` as `m` instead.

Comment: If `tryIO` isn't exactly the combinator you want, write exactly the combinator you want!